# Do you know any mail archiver software?

Tags: email, open-source, archive

I would like to archive my old mails, so that I can keep them safe. I don't want them to be in my mail client, because they are too many, and they slow it down.

The best one would be an open-source solution where I can search when I have something old to retrieve.

Do you know something like that ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. `tar` along with a good compressor like `bzip2`.  Other backup software may be substituted too.

Comment: Which mail client are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using IMAP to access your messages (and you should be!), you can just put the archived messages into a folder and then unsubscribe from that folder (and, if necessary, mark it as non-indexed).  Your mail client will then not consider it when checking for new mail, etc.  It won't slow you down, but the messages will be there and accessible if you need them.

Another solution is to export the messages using something like the `claws-mail` archive plugin.  It lets you dump the messages (even a whole folder at a time) to `.tar.gz` files or other archive types.  It works very well.